# jqgrid shows exact code on the page which should be icon

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm new with jqgrid. I want to use action buttons in actions column 
http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0573SK0
[image]

but, in my case it shows button code... like this

[image]

I used following code.

```
gridComplete : function() {
        var ids = jQuery("#gridItemPriceList").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var cl = ids[i];
            be = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' data-original-title='Edit Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#gridItemPriceList').editRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button>";
            se = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' data-original-title='Save Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#gridItemPriceList').saveRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button>";
            ca = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' data-original-title='Cancel' onclick=\"jQuery('#gridItemPriceList').restoreRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>";
            //ce = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' onclick=\"jQuery('#gridItemPriceList').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>";
            //jQuery("#gridItemPriceList").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:be+se+ce});
            jQuery("#gridItemPriceList").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], {
                act : be + se + ca
            });
        }
    },
```

but when I checked inspector, my code mixed.

[image]

which should be this

[image]

Please help me.. Thank you

Comment: Please post your jqGrid  setup options and specify which version of jqGrid is used

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you set a grid options **autoencode** to true, which causes the problem. Set it to false will maybe solve the problem